# How to get the unique items from a list<object>?

Tags: c#

I got a `List<object>` named selectedColumnList. This collection holds an object containing the properties tablename and columnname.Since the tablename repeats for different columns, i need to list out the unique tablenames from the list itself to a drop down. Anyone here to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you

```
var columnNames = selectedColumnList.Select( s => s.TableName ).Distinct();
```

This assumes that instead of `List<object>` you use `List<ClassName>` where `ClassName` is the actual object that you have put into the list, and that the class has a property called `TableName`.

Comment: And you probably should override Equals(ClassName obj) :)

Comment: @ppiotrowicz - I don't think you need to. The Select(...) call will return IEnumerable<string> (assuming TableName is a string), so the distinct will be performed on string's, and not ClassName's